# pgr_createTopology says no function matches

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgrouting

I know the attributes have to be in a certain order which I checked. Also the manual says it was renamed in version 2.0 but i can't see a difference.

```
SQL error:
function pgr_createtopology(unknown, numeric, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pgr_createTopology('edges', 0.000001, 'way', 'osm_id'...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

In statement:

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('edges', 0.000001, 'way', 'osm_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

adding explicit [type casts](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) to your parameters literals fixes the problem

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('edges'::text, 0.000001, 'way'::text, 'osm_id'::text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your pgRouting version. Extension might not be installed.

```
SELECT pgr_version();
```

you should get something like this:

```
(2.0.0,pgrouting-2.0.0,0,f26831f,master,1.53.0)
```